# Updating input value after model bind

Tags: angular

I have a text input two-way bound to a `Date` type model property:

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="model.DateStart" ngControl="dateStart" id="dateStart" #dateStart />
```

The `model.DateStart` (DateTime type) value is this:

```
2016-05-24T13:49:40.4367997+03:00
```

Which I want to display like this:

```
24.05.2016
```

I populate model data in constructor and after binding the model I update the input value using jQuery:

```
Observable.forkJoin(
                ..
        ).subscribe(
            results => {
                this.model = results[0];

                let element: any = $(input);
                element.bootstrapMaterialDatePicker();
                element.val("24.05.2016");
                console.log(element.val()) // displays "24.05.2016"
            },
```

The thing is, when the page loads the textbox displays `2016-05-24T13:49:40.4367997+03:00`.

It seems that my custom format is overwritten afterwards. Is there a way to accomplish this without setting the type of the `model.DateStart` to string and format it before binding?

I cant use input type=date because of the datetime picker component.

Answer (score 1):

try this:
create a custom pipe that will take your date as an argument and return a format of what you want ie

```
import {Pipe} from "angular2/core";

@Pipe({
    name : "formatDate"
})

export class FormatDatePipe{
    transform(value){
        var date_data = new Date(value);

        var yyyy = date_data.getFullYear().toString();
        var mm = (date_data.getMonth()+1).toString(); // getMonth() is zero-based
        var dd  = date_data.getDate().toString();

        return yyyy +"-"+ (mm[1]?mm:"0"+mm[0]) +"-"+ (dd[1]?dd:"0"+dd[0]); // returns 2016-05-16
    }
}
```

then in your display element do:

```
{{modal.DateStart|formatDate}}
```

I hope you understand how to write custom pipes; if not then use [this](https://auth0.com/blog/2015/09/03/angular2-series-working-with-pipes/) for reference

Comment: Thanks but I don't think you can use pipes in two-way binding. [(ngModel)]="model.DateStart | date: 'medium'" gives me "Cannot have a pipe in an action expression" error.

Comment: @dstr owh! Just tried it on one of my elements and hit that same snag. Sorry. Let me try another work around will update